# Visibility over Rest API gates in release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to get more information about why a gate which invokes a Rest API is failing. At the moment I am just guessing what the issue could be but out of ideas now.

[image: gates show little info]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reference to this doc: [Release deployment control using gates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/approvals/gates?view=azure-devops), we can [define a gate for a stage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deploy-using-approvals?view=azure-devops#configure-a-gate) using Invoke REST API, which will require us to set up a [Generic service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#sep-generic) to set up authenticated connection with target Rest API.

In one hand, creating a new release to check the gate status by clicking the following error button to view its detailed logs.
[image]

[image]

Therefore, we can know more information about why a gate which invokes a Rest API is failing.

In the other hand, we can call this Rest API: [Releases - Get Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/get%20release?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get release information, which will return `preDeploymentGates` property containing Gates result, and then we can find it takes each gate as a task and will return its `logUrl`, so we can download the log to view the detailed gate information.

Comment: Ah wow I had not realised that the fail icons were clickable! Thanks!